# Create an N by 1 Function Handle that Returns an array of All Zeros and Populates one Index in the Array with another Function Handle

Tags: arrays, matlab, random, function-handle

I have the following function handle:

```
f = @(t)f_0.*sin(alpha.*t).*cos(beta.*t);
```

I want to create an N by 1 function handle "array" called F (I know that you can't have an array of function handles in MATLAB) that places f at any random index position within the function handle "array." All other entries should be zero. N is any integer value.

For example, if N = 3, the correct solution is:

```
F = @(t) [f(t); 0; 0]
```

Two other correct solutions are:

```
F = @(t) [0; 0; f(t)]
```

and

```
F = @(t) [0; f(t); 0]
```

since f(t) can be placed at any random index i within F.

What is the best way to do this for any arbitrary N?

Comment: It looks like you don’t want an array of function handles, but a function that returns an array. —— Nomenclature: `f = @(t) …` creates an anonymous function. `f` is a handle to that function. `g=@sin` is also a function handle, but there is no anonymous function involved. There is little difference between `g` and `sin`, other than that `g` can be passed into a function and assigned to other variables. —— You can define a regular (named) function that creates the array you’re looking for, there is no need to make it an anonymous function. It’ll be a lot easier to write that way.

Comment: How are you going to use this handle? Your `f` is written in a way that allows an array input argument (eg `f(rand(30,20,40))`). Putting the output of this function into an array is hard. Your example, `[f(t); 0; 0]` would produce an error unless `t` is a scalar or a column vector, and in the vector case it would produce an output longer than `N`. A lot of places where handles are required in MATLAB, the function will be evaluated at many points at the same time (eg `integral`). ---- I guess only the scalar case is trivial. As I said earlier, I would write a named function for this.

Comment: "any random index position", so the parameters are `N` for the array size, and `i` for the position within that array? Your example `[f(t); 0; 0]` puts it at `i=1`, does this need to be a parameter or not? Or an actual random number as Luis' answer?

Comment: Yes. The array must have a size N and place the function handle at any random position i within the array. @CrisLuengo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the question the following function returns the requested function handle:

```
function F = farray (f, N)
    r = randi(N);
    F = @(t) [zeros(r-1, 1); f(t); zeros(N-r, 1)];
end
```

It can be used as:

```
f = @(t)f_0.*sin(alpha.*t).*cos(beta.*t);
N = 3;
F = farray(f, N);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a [*cell array* of function handles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html#brf_zvc-1). Or a cell array containing a function handle and zeros, if that's what you want:

```
f = @(t)f_0.*sin(alpha.*t).*cos(beta.*t);
N = 3;
F = repmat({0}, N, 1); % N×1 cell array of zeros
n = randi(N); % random number in [1 2 ... N] with uniform distribution
F{n} = f;
```

Comment: As Cris pointed out, I want to create a function handle that returns an array. This is almost exactly what I need, but F needs to be a 1 by 1 function handle that looks like: F = @(t) [f(t); 0;0] for any N. @LuisMendo

Comment: @JonathanFrutschy So, `F = @(t) [f(t); zeros(N-1, 1)]`? See an example [here](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/MacgI1HBVqEg05rLD0gbW3OlASkHjRJNheLMPA0jLbAKrRJNay43mER0GpC0VqhKLcov1vDTNdRRMNSMBcprGOsZaf7/DwA) Or clarify what you mean by "random" (as Cris already asked)

Comment: By random I mean that f(t) should be located at any random position within the array []. I just happened to set f(t) at the first index or i=1 as Cris pointed out for my initial example. @LuisMendo