# Create an External N by 1 Function Handle Populated with Alternating Values Using an Internal Function Handle

Tags: arrays, function, matlab, indexing, function-handle

I have the following internal function handle:

```
f = @(t)f_0.*sin(alpha.*t).*cos(beta.*t);
```

I want to create an external N by 1 function handle called F that places f in alternating positions in F as follows:

```
F = @t[f(t); 0; f(t); 0; f(t); 0; … ]
```

I would like to do this with the following function:

```
function F = farray (f,N)
    r = 2:2:N
    F = @(t) [f(t); zeros(N-r, 1)];
end
```

This doesn’t produce the desired population method. Can this be done without a for loop or another MATLAB function like toeplitz()?

Comment: `F` isn't an N by 1 anything, it's a function handle to the anonymous function you've defined, or would be if you used correct syntax. What are `f_0`, `alpha` and `beta`? What is your desired result.

Comment: @beaker Alpha, beta, and f_0 are constants. This has been done for a similar problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77284570/create-an-n-by-1-function-handle-that-returns-an-array-of-all-zeros-and-populate/77290224#77290224

Comment: What is your desired result in this case?

Comment: @beaker The desired result is the function handle that looks like: F = @t[f(t); 0; f(t); 0; f(t); 0; … ] where the size of the array in brackets [] in F is an N by 1.  I am trying to get the same result as the accepted answer of the referenced post, but using the pattern [f(t); 0; f(t); 0; …] instead of placing f(t) at any random index in the array.

Comment: Why not just `F = zeros(N,1); F(1:2:N)=f(t);`

Comment: Right, but F needs to be function handle that contains an array not it’s own array. @beaker

Comment: A function handle does not contain an array, it is a reference to a function, and that function can return an array. If you put the two lines I wrote into your `farray()` function, you can call it the same way as the code in the linked answer.

Comment: @beaker This does not return the desired output. See this image: https://ibb.co/1G9qcj4. The desired output format is output_1, which is the output of the farray() function from the previous post. I would like to achieve this same output format for output_2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `N` by `1` vector that contains `0` and `1` in alternating positions then multiply it by `f(t)`:

```
function F = farray (f,N)
    z = zeros(N, 1);
    z(1:2:end) = 1;
    F = @(t) f(t) .* z;
end
```

Another way to create the array:

```
function out = place_ft_at_alternating_positions(ft, N)
    out = zeros(N, 1);
    out(1:2:end) = ft;      
end

function F = farray (f, N)  
    F = @(t) place_ft_at_alternating_positions(f(t), N);
end
```

Comment: Using a placeholder function makes a lot of sense here.

Answer (score 2):

You can create `F` using this, assuming `N` is even

```
F = @(t) repmat( [f(t); 0], N/2, 1 );
```